# Create tab dynamically in TabLayout

Tags: android

Any idea on how to dynamically create tab in `TabLayout`? I am implement it with `ViewPager` using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, or is there any other approach? like TabWidget/TabHost? any kind of suggestion will be appreciated...

Comment: There is nothing different just use dynamic array instead of static array to create fragments dynamically with `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`

Comment: Keep adding fragments dynamically and add it to your adapter. Then assign the view pager's adapter to the adapter that you defined. That's what I did.

Comment: @AmbujKathotiya can you provide some sample on how u do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ImageListFragment fragment2 = new ImageListFragment();
    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
    bundle2.putInt("eventId", 100);
    fragment2.setArguments(bundle2);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        ImageListFragment fragment = new ImageListFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("eventId", eventIds.get(i));
        bundle.putInt("id", id);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        adapter.addFragment(fragment, eventNames.get(i));
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

So basically you need to run a loop and create new fragment everytime and add it to your adapter.